# Delete Duplicate Rows, Keep Last and Delete First

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I'm trying to come up with code that look in Column D for any duplicate text then deletes the entire row that the first duplicate is located in.  There are blanks in between the rows so using the code `.End(xl)Up` doesn't work unless you're able to target the entire column regardless of the blanks in between 
 the rows somehow.

I've tried two methods so far but neither have worked to my expectation.

This was my first method which doesn't work since the worksheet has an outline:

```
Sub test()

ActiveSheet.Range("D:D").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

This was my second method that I got from another site that runs for minutes but doesn't appear to do what I'm trying to achieve.

```
Sub Row_Dupe_Killer_Keep_Last()
Dim lrow As Long

For lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(lrow, "D") = Cells(lrow, "D").Offset(-1, 0) Then
       Cells(lrow, "D").Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
    End If

Next lrow
End Sub
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or tips?  I've been working at it for a few days now with my limited skills and haven't been able to figure a way to do it...Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: *"There are blanks in between the rows so using the code .End(xl)Up doesn't work unless you're able to target the entire column regardless of the blanks in between the rows somehow."* - Incorrect. `.End(xlUp)` will find the last cell in the entire column that has data in it. It's `.End(xlDown)` that will be halted by blanks in a column.

Comment: The second code snippet you posted should work - can you show us your sample data? Did you change column B to column D to adjust it for your needs?

Comment: @dwirony Wouldn't '.End(xl)Up' be halted when it comes across the first blank since it will think that's where the data is started?  Or would it select last cell with data and select up to row 1?  Sorry, yes I did change the column from B to D...forgot to change it and will edit the OP now.  How do I post the sample data to show you?

Comment: It's `.End(xlUp)` and it starts from row 1048576 and looks upward to the first cell with data in it, then that becomes your value :). If you can maybe make a small example (like 10 or 20 rows), screenshot a before and after, you can edit your question and add an image. You don't have the rep to embed it yet, but I can do that for you.

Comment: Note that deleting and entire row with VBA using `EntireRow.Delete` is for some reason very memory intensive and takes forever with large datasets!

Comment: @dwirony I have added an image to the OP.  In that image for example, "delete" is in Column D and I would like the code to run through column D and remove the entire row for the duplicates...in this case the cells that say "delete". However row 2293:2295 also happen to be blank before resuming with more data.

Comment: @MBB70 hmm..that is good to know since I didn't know that.  Do you think something with ~3000 rows across 18 columns would be large enough to cause the macro to run for minutes?

Comment: @J Doe the speed reduction caused by deleting entire rows with VBA is almost always painfully noticeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: Now ignores blanks**

Edit: Modified to have the ability to change the starting row

What you might want to do is pull the data into an array and search the array for duplicates.  Excel can process arrays **much** faster than it can go through each cell.

The following code does just that. It will leave D1 alone (such as in your example code) and will remove the entire row of any duplicates, only leaving the last item.

To deal with deleting the rows, we add all of the duplicates into a range object named rngDelete and delete all the rows at once. This will make it run much faster than deleting one by one.

```
Sub Row_Dupe_Killer_Keep_Last()
    Dim vData As Variant
    Dim rngDelete As Range
    Dim lrow As Long, lrowSearch As Long
    Dim lStartRow as long

    'Change this to the row you wish to start with (the top row)
    lStartRow = 22

    'Get all of the data from the cells into a variant array
    'Normally I would prefer to use usedrange, but this method is fine
    '(Note: Change the 2 to 1 if you want to include the entire column including Row number 1)
    vData = Range(Cells(lStartRow, "D").Address & ":" & Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Address)

    'Search for duplicates
    'First, loop through backwards one by one
    For lrow = UBound(vData) To LBound(vData) Step -1
        'now loop through forwards (up to the point where we have already looked)
        For lrowSearch = LBound(vData) To lrow
            'Check if we have a duplicate
            If Not IsError(vData(lrow, 1)) And Not IsError(vData(lrowSearch, 1)) Then
                If lrow <> lrowSearch And vData(lrow, 1) = vData(lrowSearch, 1) And vData(lrow, 1) <> "" Then
                    'We have a duplicate! Let's add it to our "list to delete"
                    If rngDelete Is Nothing Then
                        'if rngDelete isn't set yet...
                        Set rngDelete = Range("D" & lrowSearch + lStartRow-1)
                    Else
                        'if we are adding to rngDelete...
                        Set rngDelete = Union(rngDelete, Range("D" & lrowSearch + lStartRow-1))
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next lrowSearch
    Next lrow

    'Delete all of the duplicate rows
    If Not rngDelete Is Nothing Then
        rngDelete.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have formula errors in your data in column D? That's what it sounds like to me, I can make an update to handle and ignore those.

Comment: Thank you for coming up with this.  I did a test run of the code and it seems to delete more than just the duplicates...it seems to have removed most of the outlines as well

Comment: It deletes the entire row. Isn't that what you wanted?  What are the outlines?  If you need to only delete the duplicate **cells** then you can use `rngDelete.Rows.Delete`

Comment: It does delete the entire row however it is also deleting rows that do not have a duplicate existing in column D as well.  I can take a snippet of the outlines and include it in the OP since I'm not sure how to add an image to a comment.

Comment: Yes, that would be useful.  I did update the code to ignore blanks, too. That way rows with a blank in column D aren't deleted.

Comment: I have updated the OP with an image of the outlines.  The outlines are the expanders to the left shaped like [+]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187210/discussion-between-hmvba-and-j-doe).

Comment: HMVBA helped me figure the solution to this in chat for anyone reading this in the future.  I had to expand my outline first then the code ran perfect

Comment: Glad we figured it out. Just check out my change to modify the starting row. Otherwise, the wrong rows will get deleted!

Answer (score 1):

This should help you out.

```
    Option Explicit

    Const c_intMaxBlanks As Integer = 5
    Const c_AbsoluteMaxRowsInSheet As Integer = 5000

    Public Sub RunIt()
        Row_Dupe_Killer_Keep_Last ActiveSheet.Range("D:D")
    End Sub

    Public Sub Row_Dupe_Killer_Keep_Last(rngCells As Range)

        Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
        Dim intBlankCnt As Integer
        Dim intMaxBlanks As Integer
        Dim blnIsDone As Boolean
        Dim intSaveStartRow As Integer
        Dim blnStartCnt As Boolean
        Dim strTemp As String
        Dim strCheck As String
        Dim intI As Integer
        Dim intJ As Integer
        Dim intSaveEndRow As Integer


        'First, Count the consecutive blanks
        blnIsDone = False
        blnStartCnt = False
        intSaveStartRow = 0
        intSaveEndRow = 0
        intBlankCnt = 0
        iRow = 1
        iCol = rngCells.Column
        Do While (Not blnIsDone)
            'Check for blank Row using length of string
            If (Len(Trim(rngCells.Cells(iRow, 1).Value)) < 1) Then  
                If Not blnStartCnt Then
                    intSaveStartRow = iRow
                    blnStartCnt = True
                Else
                    If (intSaveStartRow + intBlankCnt) <> iRow Then
                        'restart
                        intSaveStartRow = iRow
                        intBlankCnt = 0
                    End If
                End If
                intBlankCnt = intBlankCnt + 1
            Else
                'restart
                blnStartCnt = False
                intBlankCnt = 0
            End If

            intSaveEndRow = iRow

            If intBlankCnt >= c_intMaxBlanks Then blnIsDone = True

            'Stop Loop: Maybe Infinite"
            If iRow > c_AbsoluteMaxRowsInSheet Then Exit Do
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Loop

        'Now, loop through each row in the column and check values.
        For intI = intSaveEndRow To 2 Step -1
            strTemp = LCase(Trim(rngCells.Cells(intI, 1).Value))
            For intJ = intSaveEndRow To 2 Step -1
                If intJ <> intI Then
                    strCheck = LCase(Trim(rngCells.Cells(intJ, 1).Value))
                    If strTemp = strCheck Then
                        'Found a dup, delete it
                        rngCells.Cells(intJ, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                    'ElseIf Len(strCheck) < 1 Then
                    '    'Delete the blank line
                    '    rngCells.Cells(intJ, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                    End If
                End If
            Next intJ
        Next intI

    End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm this code seems to get close...  Is there a way to not delete any blanks?  It doesn't appear to delete any rows where Column D has duplicate numbers..  The numbers are formatted as General if that matters.

Comment: I will edit the code and comment out the blank deletion.

Comment: OK, it will not delete blanks now.

Answer (score 1):

This method avoids the use of `EntireRow.Delete`, which is notoriously slow. The contents are cleared and the dataset is sorted to remove gaps.

EDIT: switched to For Next to enable searching upwards from the bottom; also cleaned up sort routine generated by the macro recorder...I never seem to have that routine on-hand when I need it :).

Note: this will also not work with an outline...whatever you did to make it work for the other answer will need to be done for this one as well.

I am curious if the Clear/Sort approach works for you and if it speeds up your routine.

```
Option Explicit
Sub RemoveFirstDuplicate()
    Dim myDataRange As Range, iCounter As Long, myDuplicate As Range, lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("D1000000").End(xlUp).Row
    Set myDataRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D" & lastRow)
    'searching up to the second row (below the field name assumed to be in row 1)...you may need to adjust where the loop stops
    For iCounter = myDataRange.Cells.Count To 2 Step -1
        With myDataRange
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myDataRange, myDataRange.Item(iCounter)) > 1 Then
                Set myDuplicate = .Find(What:=myDataRange.Item(iCounter), After:=myDataRange.Item(iCounter), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
                Range("D" & myDuplicate.Row).ClearContents
            End If
        End With
    Next iCounter
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=myDataRange.Offset(1, 0)
        .SetRange myDataRange
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't realize you were just working with data in column D...you can just enter `myDuplicate = vbnullstring` in lieu of `Range("D" & myDuplicate.Row).ClearContents`

Comment: This code actually seems to almost get there.  It looks like it is deleting the second duplicate instead of the first duplicate and seems to do something funky...like the in column D is being pasted over?